# React native: Axios Get accusing Network Error

Tags: javascript, react-native, networking, axios

I'm coding my first react-native program with Axios and found problems making get calls. Sinse it's a Network error I assume the problem is somewhere below.

Api.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://192.168.15.8:3333",
});

export default api;
```

index.js

```
 async function loadIncidents() {
    if (loading) {
        return;
    }

    if (total > 0 && incidents.length === total) {
        return;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    try {
        const response = await api.get("/incidents", {
            params: { page },
        });

        setIncidents([...incidents, ...response.data]);
        setTotal(response.headers["x-total-count"]);
        setPage(page + 1);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Ocorreu um erro: ', err)
    }
    setLoading(false);
}

  useEffect(() => {
    loadIncidents();
  }, []);
```

[image: error:]

Comment: You are using await but not handling the response. check asnyc await on the mozilla docs

Answer (score 0):

you can use `try() catch()`

```
async function loadIncidents() {
    if (loading) {
      return;
    }

    if (total > 0 && incidents.length === total) {
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);

    let response;
    try {
     response = await api.get("incidents", {
      params: { page },
    });
    } catch (ex) {
       console.log(ex);
    }
    setIncidents([...incidents, ...response.data]);
    setTotal(response.headers["x-total-count"]);
    setPage(page + 1);
    setLoading(false);
  }
```